# How to remove or delete single cron job using linux command?

Tags: cron

I have created cron jobs for my site which is listed below and they are working fine. I print all cron job by using this PHP script:

```
$cronfiles=exec('crontab -l',$output);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
```

Which outputs:

> `[0] => 0 0 * * * wget php -q http://www.example.com/report_send.php`
>   `[1] => 0 0 * * * wget php -q http://www.example.com/event_reminder.php`
>   `[2] => 0 0 * * * wget php -q http://www.example.com/user_reminder.php`
>   `[3] => * * * * * wget php -q http://www.example.com/cleardata.php`

Now I want to delete or remove a single cron job from my server through command. For example I want to remove cron job "`0 0 * * * wget php -q http://www.example.com/event_reminder.php`" from server.

I tried `crontab -r` command which removes all cron job from my server but i want to remove specific cron job.

Can you please help me for solution?

Answer (score 132):

1. To add a job to crontab:

   ```
   (crontab -u mobman -l ; echo "*/5 * * * * perl /home/mobman/test.pl") | crontab -u mobman -
   ```
2. To remove a job from crontab:

   ```
   crontab -u mobman -l | grep -v 'perl /home/mobman/test.pl'  | crontab -u mobman -
   ```
3. Remove everything from crontab:

   ```
   crontab -r
   ```

Nothing is tricky: `-` is STDOUT in Linux!

Comment: **Greg:** Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/719877/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Please replace 1. To add a job to crontab with (crontab -u mobman -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/5 * * * * perl /home/mobman/test.pl") | crontab -u mobman - (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880290/how-do-i-create-a-crontab-through-a-script)

Comment: @YasiruG I think `crontab -l 2 > /dev/null` is only necessary if you don't want to see the message `no crontab for <user>` if there is no existing cron job. By the way, we don't need the option `-u mobman` if we want to add the cron job for the current user.

Comment: hi, how if i only add if cron not registered/not exist before?

Comment: `-` has no special (syntactic) meaning: it's just a string as, for instance, `"a"`. It's some sort of convention, though, that some programs interpret `-` as "read from stdin". (The actual stdin is usually `/dev/stdin`).

Answer (score 47):

From a root prompt type

```
crontab -e
```

You can now edit the file and remove the line you want remove. You can also use this to edit crontab for users if you have the prompt for that user.

By the way: I prefer to add cronjobs to `/etc/crontab`. Seems a bit more flexible to me.

Comment: This seems easier and makes more sense than script wizardry, but I do wish I was more wizard like.

Comment: Great for manual changes, but for automation check the script above --

Comment: unless you are already on root user, this will not edit root crontab

Answer (score 17):

## View Users Cronjob

Use the following syntax to view **waqleh** user's cronjob:

```
crontab -u waqleh -l
```

## View current user's Cronjob

Just type the following command:

```
crontab -l
```

## Specific user's cron file

```
crontab -u USERNAME -l
```

This should list the contents of the crontab script.

## View /etc/crontab

A cronjob can be also run from /etc/crontab file. To view it, enter:

```
less /etc/crontab
```

## Remove all cron jobs

**If and only if** you want to stop all cron jobs, you can remove them entirely with:

```
crontab -r
```

This **removes the entire crontab file** for current user so be careful if you've got other cron jobs listed in there!

## Add/Edit/Delete cron job(s)

### Your user's cron file

```
crontab -e
```

### Specific user's cron file

```
crontab -u USERNAME -e
```

each line represent a cron job. You can remove any cron (if you are using nano by clicking ctrl+k) then save and exit

Answer (score 7):

```
crontab -l | grep -v 'wget php -q http://www.example.com/event_reminder.php' | crontab -
```

`crontab -l` lists the current crontab jobs

`grep -v` filter some line

`crontab -` adds all the printed stuff into the crontab file.

Comment: This explains in detail the piped bash commands given by @rinzwind above. basically filter out what you want to remove using grep and pass all that to crontab at the command line again. The '\n' characters will separate cron job entries. The | command puts the output of the previous program into stdout by default, and this is represented as '-' as the input for the last crontab command.

Answer (score 3):

To comment out the cron job at *say* line 2, use this command in your shell:

```
crontab -l | sed '2 s/^/#/g' | crontab -
```

Replace the number `2` by the line number of your choice, or remove it altogether to comment out all the jobs.

It can be programmatically called via a cron job itself, for instance to comment all jobs at 12:00, add this line to your crontab:

```
0 12 * * * crontab -l | sed 's/^/#/g' | crontab -
```

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 0):

For those who like me can't get out of vi:

```
EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

In editor you can delete/change everything what you want

Comment: This describes how to change the editor for crontab, but not answering the question

Answer (score 0):

Just use pipes as follows

```
crontab -l | grep -v 'your_job' | head -1 | crontab -
```

For example

```
crontab -l | grep -v '/usr/local/bin/my_script.sh' | head -1 | crontab -
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

The best way to go about removing individual crontab jobs is simply to go into the script and comment out the line of script that performs the operation.